# Codeigniter ReCaptcha and form validation config

Tags: codeigniter, validation, recaptcha

Below is a snippet of my code:

auth.php

```
    // Login the user
public function login(){

    $view_data = new stdClass;
    // Form Data
    $view_data->login_form = $this->auth_lib->get_login_form_data();
    $view_data->reg_form = $this->auth_lib->get_reg_form_data();
    $view_data->login_recaptcha = '';
    $view_data->reg_recaptcha = '';

    // Set an attempt
    $this->auth_model->set_form_submit('Login');

    // Get number of attemps
    $login_count = $this->auth_model->get_form_submit_count('Login', 3600);

    if($login_count >= 3){
        // 3 or more attempts

        $view_data->login_recaptcha = recaptcha();
        $privkey = $this->config->item('recaptcha_private_key');
        $remoteip = $_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR'];
        $challenge = $this->input->post('recaptcha_challenge_field');
        $response = $this->input->post('recaptcha_response_field');

        $resp = recaptcha_check_answer($privkey, $remoteip, $challenge, $response);
        if($resp->is_valid !== TRUE){
            $this->form_validation->set_rules('recaptcha_response_field', 'Recaptcha Response Field', 'required');
            $this->form_validation->set_rules('recaptcha_challenge_field', 'Recaptcha Challenge Field', 'required|matches[recaptcha_response_field]');
        }

    }

    if($this->form_validation->run() == FALSE){
        // Not valid input
        $template_data = $this->template->load('auth/login', $view_data);
        $this->load->view($template_data->template, $template_data);    

    }else{
        // Valid input

    }

}
```

form_validation.php

```
    $config = array(
            'auth/login' => array(
                    array(
                    'field' => 'login_username',
                    'label' => 'Username',
                    'rules' => 'required|min_length[4]|max_length[12]|'
                    ),
                    array(
                    'field' => 'login_password',
                    'label' => 'Password',
                    'rules' => 'required|min_length[6]|max_length[16]'
                    ),              
            ),
            'auth/register' => array(
                    array(
                    'field' => 'reg_username',
                    'label' => 'Username',
                    'rules' => 'required|min_length[4]|max_length[12]|'
                    ),
                    array(
                    'field' => 'email',
                    'label' => 'Email',
                    'rules' => 'required|min_length[3]|valid_email|'
                    ),
                    array(
                    'field' => 'email_again',
                    'label' => 'Email Again',
                    'rules' => 'required|min_length[3]|valid_email|matches[email]'
                    ),
                    array(
                    'field' => 'reg_password',
                    'label' => 'Password',
                    'rules' => 'required|min_length[6]|max_length[16]'
                    ),              
            ),
    );
```

Everything works, I have my form validation rules set in a config file "form_validation.php" and the are labelled "controller/method" as shown in the CI manual to be automatically used when the corresponding controller/method is called.

If the login count is greater than or equal to the defined amount (3 in this case) then the ReCaptcha form is shown.

The problem is this, if the user enters the wrong ReCaptcha and fails to enter information required in the other form fields then only the ReCaptcha error is displayed. If the user enters the ReCaptcha field correctly and *fails* to enter the information in the other fields those errors will be displayed.

If set the validation rules in the controller like so :

```
$this->form_validation->set_rules('login_username', 'Username', 'required');
```

Then the error will be displayed if it exists beside the ReCaptcha error if it's present like you would expect.

I would like any or all errors that exist to be displayed, how can I do this with out having to set my validations in the controller?

Am I just missing something simple? Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

For now until I find a better solutions allowing me to use the form_validation.php config file, I have decided to use this method below.

```
public function register(){

        if($login_count >= 3){
        // 3 or more attempts

        $view_data->reg_recaptcha = recaptcha();
        $privkey = $this->config->item('recaptcha_private_key');
        $remoteip = $_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR'];
        $challenge = $this->input->post('recaptcha_challenge_field');
        $response = $this->input->post('recaptcha_response_field');

        $resp = recaptcha_check_answer($privkey, $remoteip, $challenge, $response);

    }

    if( isset($resp->is_valid) && ($resp->is_valid !== TRUE) ){

        $this->set_validation_rules('register', true);      
    }else{
        $this->set_validation_rules('register', false);
    }       

    if($this->form_validation->run() == FALSE){
        // Not valid input
        $template_data = $this->template->load('auth/register', $view_data);
        $this->load->view($template_data->template, $template_data);    

    }else{
        // Valid input

    }
}


public function set_validation_rules($form = '', $recaptcha = FALSE){

    if($recaptcha !== FALSE){
        $this->form_validation->set_rules('recaptcha_response_field', 'Recaptcha Response Field', 'required');
        $this->form_validation->set_rules('recaptcha_challenge_field', 'Recaptcha Challenge Field', 'required|matches[recaptcha_response_field]');
    }

    if($form === 'login'){
        $this->form_validation->set_rules('login_username', 'Username', 'required');
        $this->form_validation->set_rules('login_password', 'Password', 'required');
    }

    if($form === 'register'){
        $this->form_validation->set_rules('reg_username', 'Username', 'required|min_length[4]|max_length[12]');
        $this->form_validation->set_rules('email', 'Email', 'required|min_length[3]|valid_email');
        $this->form_validation->set_rules('email_again', 'Email Again', 'required|min_length[3]|valid_email|matches[email]');
        $this->form_validation->set_rules('reg_password', 'Password', 'required|min_length[6]|max_length[16]');         
    }
```

This isn't what I wanted to do, as stated above I would like to keep my validation in a config file. So if you have better solution please share! Until then this will do.

Thanks!